# To calculate the time needed for a vacuum robot to cover whole area

Tags: vehicle-routing, simulation

A vacuum robot runs on randomized direction when it is operating in a room.

I want to know how long it takes to fully cover the whole area (or at least most part of the area) with given information:

1. the area in the room is 10 square meters.
2. the dimension of the round shape robot is 40 centimeter.
3. the robot travels at a speed of 20 meters per minute.
4. the robot only travels straightly.
5. the robot forwards to a random direction when hit the wall.

Below the left is a vacuum robot. The right is the imagination of a working robot.

I'm not sure if it relates to routing problem or other Operations Research method. (neither sure if it is a problem that can be optimized by Operation Research but just allow me to put it here.)

Can you please advise how to solve this problem? Thank you

[image]

Comment: *"or at least most part of the area"* needs to be defined properly. There might be an area on the plain (in the extreme case a point) that is never touched with a positive probability which implies that the expected time of covering the entire area is infinity.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting mathematics question. I suggest that you post this question to either [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and use the keywords *expectation*, *expected-value* and *geometric-probability*. This question or its variants may have already been solved. Otherwise, you will know if the question is relatively new or still open.

Comment: @Mark K, would you see [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269297110_Path_planning_algorithm_development_for_autonomous_vacuum_cleaner_robots) or [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/628/what-algorithm-should-i-implement-to-program-a-room-cleaning-robot) links. They would be helpful.

Comment: @r.beigi, A.Omidi, thank you both for the comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if a closed form solution is achievable. Assuming you can quantify how the robot selects its next direction when it hits a boundary (uniform over the entire circle, uniform over directions not within some angle of its last direction, some nonuniform distribution, ...), you could fairly easily build a simulation model (starting with an empty room -- furniture could be included but would make the model much more complex). Run the simulation a zillion times and you have an estimated distribution for the time to achieve a specified level of coverage. There are other complicating factors you could build in if you chose (such as battery life -- the vac might run out of juice before it achieved the target coverage level).